# how to hide 'subnav' items in Buddypress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, buddypress

so guys i have been trying to figure out to hide the subnav item into a drop down list how should i approach it? can it be done with css or i have to do some coding work to in order to get it function properly. what i am trying to do is when my mouse hovers over 'activity' 'profile' it drops down the sub nav items for the user 
and any help how to hide entry title on a specific page i tried doing it like this

```
entry-title{
                  display:none;
       }
```

and it hides it from the whole site and em just trying to shut it off from the buddypress pages..

any answers with examples will be highly appericiated

[image: this what em talkin about]

Answer (score 0):

Buddypress adds a `bbpress` class to the body on buddypress related pages, you can use that to identify it as a bbpress page

```
.bbpress .entry-title{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Could you show a fiddle of the issue? or a link to the page( if it's not on localhost)

Comment: sadly it is on a local host,i dont really have any issue with coding i just need an example on how to approach these 'subnav' items as a drop down list do i need to use wordpress function or can i just do with html and css,i m new to this wordpress thing so things get tricky for me sometimes.
if you can post any example coding on this i can figure out the rest of it myself like for 'Activity" section how to hide its subnav item in a drop down list, i am looking for something simple like when u hover mouse over it all items come down in a drop down list

Comment: and em using color mag theme in case u wana know

Comment: Can't you make a wordpress menu? appearence > menus ? if you create a menu with subitems there you can include them in your site with [wp_nav_menu](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/)

Comment: yo bro i added an image for better understanding what you are telling is the site navigation thing i am talking about the nav bar in the content area i need to put these in a drop down list

Comment: Can't do much without the HTML structure, if that ul is wrapped in the main menu you can do `ul.content_area_nav_bar li :hover ul.sub_nav_bar{ display:block}` if it's seperate you should edit the structure or if you can't you can do it with javascript

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways you can achieve that.
Using javascript.

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("settings") != -1) {
$(".entry-title").hide();
}
```

Copy the buddypress folder into your theme folder follow this link `https://codex.buddypress.org/themes/theme-compatibility-1-7/a-quick-look-at-1-7-theme-compatibility/`
and then you can add your own class into those pages and then you can

```
.customeclass .entry-title{
    display:none;
}
```

or simply you can use Jeffrey Troost suggestion

Comment: i already checked buddypress codex i just wanted to see someone else approach the subnav menu i am kinda new to this so i was looking for something to start off with if u can give any examples on subnav menu.i ll highly appericiate any kind of help on this